# looking for Tkinter mainloop() alternative that continues code after window is destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

I am looking for Tkinter mainloop() alternative that continues code after window is destroyed. Currently my code is written as follows:

```
root = tk.Tk()
recObj = Twiz_Soft.Recorder()
app = MyApp(root,recObj)
root.mainloop()
```

Contained within MyApp is a method that calls:

```
root = tk.Toplevel()
recObj = Twiz_Soft.Recorder(self.branch)
app = Twiz_app.BranchEditor(root,recObj)
root.mainloop()
# Code Im trying to execute once BranchEditor window is destroyed
```

and maintained in a separate file:

```
class BranchEditor(object):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent, recObj):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.recObj = recObj
        self.root.title("Twiz_BranchEditor")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()
        exitb = tk.Button(self.root,text='Exit',fg='red',command=self.root.destroy).pack()
```

Reference to the 'Twiz' package is a custom block of code I'm writing.

I have found solution to my problem that utilizes:

```
var = tk.IntVar()
button = tk.Button(inputFrame, text="exit",fg='green', command=lambda: var.set(1))
button.pack()

print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(var)
print("done waiting.")
```

However I was hoping for something a little more elegant since triggering `button.wait_variable(var)` within an init function seems pretty clumsy and goes against my typical expectation of syntax.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t call `mainloop` more than once. You don’t need to call it for each `Toplevel`. Any code after the one call will run once the window has been destroyed.

If you need to wait until the `Toplevel` has been destroyed, you can call its `wait_window` method.

Comment: Where is the place best to find documentation on all this tkinter stuff? top result on google doesnt always seem to do the trick. there is no way I would have found 'wait_window' on my own..

Comment: @MtLeftovers: the very best place is the official tcl/tk documentation at [tcl.tk](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/contents.htm). It is canonical and comprehensive. You just have to do a little mental translation of the tcl commands into python, and the python docs give you [a guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#navigating-the-tcl-tk-reference-manual) for how to do that. The website [tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/) is also a great resource.